# Airtable API key generation proble

Tags: airtable

i am trying to integrate Airtable with voiceflow but i need my secret AP key to do that but i cant find it anywhere even in the documentation where it is mentioned after bearer and there is no check box at the top of it, plus i cant even find it in the account settings where it says that you can generate api key but the option is not there. Would really apricate some help

I tried creating new tokens
I tried finding it in the documentation
I tried to go to the account settings to generate it from there but still cant